# SpriteKit - Scale in one direction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scale, skaction, collision

How do I make an object grow in one direction is SpriteKit?

Ultimately, I would like to have a node be inserted where the user touches and have each end of a line scale until it hits another object in the same category or hits the edge of the screen.  I understand how to have it scale on an axis and I can then cancel the scaling after one collision is detected but I want both directions to scale independently until a collision is made for each. I am new to SpriteKit so my searches may be using the wrong terms but I have not been able to find anything relevant.

Code to add a "wall" where the user touches

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch * touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        [self addWallAtLocation:location];
    }
}

-(void)addWallAtLocation:(CGPoint)location{

    int odd_or_even = arc4random() % 2;

    SKSpriteNode * wall = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]     size:CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
    wall.position = location;

    wall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
    wall.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    wall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;
    wall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;

    [self addChild:wall];

    SKAction * grow;

    if (odd_or_even == 1) {
        grow = [SKAction scaleYTo:300 duration:2];
    } else {
        grow = [SKAction scaleXTo:300 duration:2];
    }

    [wall runAction:grow];
}
```

[image]

How I want it to work:
Touch 1 makes the horizontal line from a point which shoots out in both directions on the x-axis until both ends hit the edge of the screen.  Touch 2 would then create a point which shoots out in both directions on the y-axis until the lower end hits the wall created by Touch 1 and the upper end hits the edge of the screen.  The lines (scaled points) are generated where the user touches.  So I do not want the part of the vertical line that is highlighted by the red box to be there.

Scaling in one direction is just a solution I see to this problem, if there is a better way of going about it I will certainly try that other solution.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT FOR UPDATED QUESTION:
It sounds like you might be asking "how to scale a thing in a single axis, but then stop the scaling of that single axis in one direction only when it collides with another thing"? There isn't a simple way to do that just using actions, but you you could do some slight of hand by manipulating the anchor point of a sprite. Or, probably more appropriately, you should use 2 sprites per touch, with one action sending one north, and another action sending the other one south. Maybe like this:

```
-(void)someMethod{

    SKSpriteNode *touch2TopPart = [SKSpriteNode node];
    SKSpriteNode *touch2BottomPart = [SKSpriteNode node];
    touch2TopPart.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, 0);
    touch2BottomPart.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, 1);

    touch2TopPart.name = @"touch2TopPart";
    touch2BottomPart.name = @"touch2BottomPart";

    SKAction *sendTopPartUp = [SKAction scaleYTo:100 duration:2];
    SKAction *sendBottomPartDown = [SKAction scaleYTo:100 duration:2];

    [touch2TopPart runAction:sendTopPartUp withKey:@"sendTopPartUp"];
    [touch2BottomPart runAction:sendBottomPartDown withKey:@"sendBottomPartDown"];

}

-(void)whateverTheCollisonMethodIsCalledBetweenThingAandThingB
{
    SKSpriteNode *somePartMovingInASingleDirection = thingAOrWhatever;

    [somePartMovingInASingleDirection removeAllActions];

}
```

---ORIGINAL ANSWER
I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but you already have the actions for scaling in just X or Y, so here's the simple usage for removing one of those actions after physics is simulated. You might be looking for how to detect a specific collision between two entities, but I can't be sure.

```
-(void)someMethod{

    SKSpriteNode *thisSprite = [SKSpriteNode node];

    thisSprite.name = @"spriteRunningActions";

    SKAction *growX = [SKAction scaleXTo:100 duration:2];
    SKAction *growY = [SKAction scaleYTo:100 duration:2];

    [thisSprite runAction:growX withKey:@"actionCurrentlyScalingX"];
    [thisSprite runAction:growY withKey:@"actionCurrentlyScalingY"];

}

-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    SKSpriteNode *thatSprite = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"spriteRunningActions"];

    //stop a given action
    [thatSprite removeActionForKey:@"actionCurrentScalingX"];
    [thatSprite removeActionForKey:@"actionCurrentScalingY"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the anchor point like below made the "lines" scale in one direction.

```
wall.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

Comment: Yup, just like how I pointed out they would in my answer, but your question wanted them scaling in both directions at first and then only stopping in a single direction, so the second edit showed you how to do that.